# "No input file specified" error when trying to run Homestead

Tags: terminal

I've searched all over the internet to find the solution to this. I can't find ANYTHING, Vagrant is up and running, everything works simply PERFECTLY except this. When I browse to http://learn.app:5656 (which by the way is my host) it just gives me a simple "No input file specified." error. Here is the code in the Homestead.yaml file, if anyone is interested:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/Desktop/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
- map: learn.app
  to: /home/vagrant/code/my-first-app/public

variables:
- key: APP_ENV
  value: local
```